# Python MySQL-Connector: Ошибка №2003

Tags: mysql, python

Я делаю своего личного бота, и сейчас пилю интеграцию с MySQL.
Во время попытки подключиться к серверу, консоль мне выдаёт следующую ошибку:

```
2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'neferoncraft.pp.ua:3306' (10061 Подключение не установлено, т.к. конечный компьютер отверг запрос на подключение)
```

Код:

```
config = {
    "user": "root",
    "password": "****",
    "host": "neferoncraft.pp.ua",
    "database": "****"
}
connection = None
try:
    connection = mysql.connector.connect(**config)
except mysql.connector.Error as err:
    if err.errno == errorcode.ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR:
        print('ВНИМАНИЕ!!! Неверный логин или пароль от базы данных!')
    elif err.errno == errorcode.ER_BAD_DB_ERROR:
        print("ВНИМАНИЕ!!! Данной базы данных не существует!")
    else:
        print(err)
```

Как решить эту проблему?

Comment: Настроить neferoncraft.pp.ua так, чтобы MySQL был доступен на порте 3306.

Comment: Ммм, а каким образом?

Comment: Это очень общий вопрос. Надо убедиться, что СУБД слушает нужный адрес, надо проверить, что брандмауэр не ограничивает доступ к порту на этом адресе и т.д. и т.п.

Comment: меня интересует, на пк с бд какая ос, какой версии питона вы пользуетесь, какуя библиотеку вы используете для подклбючения к бд?